# Python casting from long during addition to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, types, casting

Why does Python not cast long numbers to numpy floats when doing sth. like

```
a = np.array([10.0, 56.0]) + long(10**47)
```

The dtype of the variable `a` is `object`. I did not expect this when during an maximum likelihood optimization problem one fit parameter B was an integer and thus 10**B became a long.

Is this due to fear of precision loss?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa apparently not. At least with Python 2.7.10 I get `array([1e+47, 1e+47], dtype=object)`, so numpy is converting the objects to python objects.

Comment: @user545424 I removed my comment when I noticed my mistake. :)

Comment: Just curious, are you minimizing the negative log likelihood? It often helps with these minimizations to work in log space to avoid very large/small values. For example, to compute the probability of observing 10 events in a histogram with an expected mean of 2, you might naively compute `np.exp(-2)*2**10/factorial(10)`, but if you work in log space this becomes `-2 + 10*2 - lnfact(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because python is able to store arbitrarily long integers and so numpy realizes that it can't safely cast the result to a known data type. Therefore, it falls back to treating the array as an array of python objects and multiplies elementwise using python's rules (which casts to a float).

You can see what the result type is by using [`np.result_type`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html):

```
>>> np.result_type(np.array([10.0, 56.0],long(10**47))
dtype('O')
```

Based on the documentation for `np.result_type` what happens is:

First, `np.min_scalar_type()` is called on each of the inputs:

```
>>> np.min_scalar_type(np.array([10.0, 56.0]))
dtype('float64')
>>> np.min_scalar_type(long(10**47))
dtype('O')
```

Second, the result is determined by combining these types using np.promote_types:

```
>>> np.promote_types(np.float64,np.dtype('O'))
dtype('O')
```